# How to change email to mobile in Laravel 10 to forget the password?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and using Laravel 10. I used Laravel UI for auth setup and it's working fine but I want to use mobile auth instead of email auth. How can I do it?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only('mobile');
    }

    public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['mobile' => 'required|numeric']);
        $user = User::query()->where('mobile', $request->mobile)->first();
        var_dump($user);
        if (!$user) {
           alert('there is not any user');
        }
        $token = Password::broker()->createToken($user);//this function
        $user->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
        return back();
    }
}
```

I get this error

> Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker::createToken(): Argument #1 ($user) must be of type Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword, null given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\yazd\vakera\app\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController.php on line 48

Comment: check that your `$user` in `$user = User::query()->where('mobile', $request->mobile)->first();` is valid. Does user with mobile `$request->mobile` really exist? is `$request->mobile` not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Laravel 10 sendResetLinkEmail() function need to defined credentials(), if you're getting mobile number in request than you need to get email from user object pass manually as credentials() in function, please check the function code :

```
public function sendResetLinkEmail(Request $request)
{
    // $this->validateEmail($request);
    $this->validate($request, ['mobile' => 'required|numeric']);
    $user = User::whereMobile($request->mobile)->first();

    if ($user) {
        // We will send the password reset link to this user. Once we have attempted
        // to send the link, we will examine the response then see the message we
        // need to show to the user. Finally, we'll send out a proper response.
        
        // $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink(
        //     $this->credentials($request)   // remove this because it's fatch email from request but you don't pass email in request
        // );
        // need to add maually user's email to  send reset link
        $response = $this->broker()->sendResetLink($user->email);

        return $response == Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
                    ? $this->sendResetLinkResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetLinkFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    return back()
            ->withInput($request->only('mobile'))
            ->withErrors(['mobile' => "User not found with this mobile number"]);

}
```